How can I fix Postgres deadlock errors in Minitest?
I am using Minitest and Postgres to test my Rails website. When I added tests for model and controller, I started getting Postgresql deadlock errors in different tests.
UPDATE
I found the problem. I get these errors when there are too many tests. I have 50 tests and everything works well. When I add a few more tests I get errors. How can I fix them?
Error:
Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActiveRecord::Deadlocked: PG::TRDeadlockDetected: ERROR:  deadlock detected LINE 7: DELETE FROM "videos";                     ^ DETAIL:  Process 11456 waits for RowExclusiveLock on relation 42608 of database 42434; blocked by process 10460. Process 10460 waits for ShareRowExclusiveLock on relation 42564 of database 42434; blocked by process 11456. HINT:  See server log for query details. 

Other errors:
Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "accounts_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(825136781) already exists.

Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: connection is closed


You name three different exceptions in your question. What line of your test raises what exception?

@spickermann they raise in different tests each time, not only Like model tests. Sometimes 3 tests are failed, sometimes 10

When you share two tests and three different error messages that are not related, then we will not be able to help. I suggest you pick one test at the time. And then share the test, the code of the models, the database schema of those models, and the error message from that specific test.

This is somewhat unrelated but you don't want dependent: :destroy on your followers and followees associations. That will cause all the followed Profile records to get deleted when you delete a profile!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@spickermann updated a question

@toliak Those are only some error messages. How do you expect people to be able to help you without the code or the tests to analyze or reproduce the issue?

Do you have locking in your postgres table? Because deadlocks when running tests are pretty unusual.

@TarynEast how can I check this?

Comment this line in test_helper.rb
parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors, with: :threads)

